# JAXB XJC options: Alternative to com.sun.tools.xjc.Options which is Java9-friendly and OSGi-friendly

Tags: jaxb, osgi, xjc, java-9

In our framework we have an interface with this method in the public API:

```
JaxbConfiguration newJaxbConfiguration(Options xjcOpts);
```

In the implementation, we do something like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Options;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model;
...

public JaxbConfiguration newJaxbConfiguration(Options xjcOpts) {
    Model model = ModelLoader.load(xjcOpts, ...);
    ...
}
```

However, both OSGi and Java 9's jigsaw don't like that we use `com.sun.tools.xjc.Options`, not in our implementation and especially not in our public API interface.

How can we get rid of it?

Comment: Can you explain what JaxbConfiguration is and what you want to achieve with the method?

Comment: [Here's the code of that JaxbConfiguration](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/builder/conf/impl/JaxbConfigurationImpl.java). @mario-fusco Do you have any idea what we do with that?

Answer (score 2):

The [JDeps website](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool) lists some of the JDK internal APIs and the recommended way to replace their usage. However, the use of ModelLoader.load() is not mentioned. My guess is that this use case has not come up enough to get the attention of the JDeps team.

My recommendation would be to refactor this method so that

1. you pass in the data you're using to construct the Options argument, instead of passing in the Options argument
2. use that data to construct your JaxbConfiguration object instead of converting from the internal Model.

You don't mention what JaxbConfiguration is or what library it's from so it's hard for me to say exactly how to construct it. Anyway, this answer is about how to remove the use of the internal API. How to construct a JaxbConfiguration is probably a different question.